# compress data by gzip and add additionally information in shell

Tags: linux, bash

I want to use the bash command to compress a file and add additional information to the beginning of the compressed file.

For example, I have a file `hello.txt` to be compressed.

I can compress this file with the following command.

```sh
gzip -c hello.txt > hello.txt.gz
```

I want to add some additional text information.

I can insert text to file by the following command.

```sh
echo "SEND BY JACK" > hello.txt.gz
```

But the compressed content was removed.

How can I get the following format by bash command in linux?

```
SEND BY JACK
<compressed contents>
```

Comment: This thread would help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264980/how-to-append-a-line-in-a-zipped-file-without-unzipping/264983

Answer (score 1):

`gzip` is a binary format. Don't attempt to add ascii after you have compressed. Instead, append the contents (use `>>` instead of `>` to append) of the original file to your new string with something like:

```
echo "SEND BY JACK" > tmp.txt
cat hello.txt >> tmp.txt
gzip -c tmp.txt > hello.txt.gz
rm -f tmp.txt
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I solved this problem by `cat`. What I want to do is send additional text information and compressed data to the server. I save this two-part information in two files `line` and `tmp.gz` , then `cat line1 tmp.gz  | nc 127.0.0.1 8787`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temporary file if you stream the output of a commands block to the `gzip` command:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

{
  echo "SEND BY JACK"
  cat hello.txt
} |
gzip >hello.txt.gz
```